# How to set an element's textContent, without the string getting trimmed?

Tags: javascript, html, trim

I'm trying to set an element's text content (a `div` element) to something the user has given as input. I don't really want to use `element.innerHTML = (...)` because then it could be parsed as HTML code instead of plain text, so I'm using `element.textContent = (...)`.
 However, there can be spaces at the beginning (and at the end) of the input string, and I don't want the string to be trimmed before inserted into the element.
With `innerHTML`, I could simply replace all spaces with `&nbsp;`, but `textContent` doesn't show that as a space, but as plain `&nbsp;`.

How can I do it? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why not doing an `String.prototype.replace('&nbsp',' ')` after textContent

Comment: @TahaAzzabi Yes, that could work as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make whitespace render as it exists in the DOM, you can apply [`white-space: pre-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) in CSS:

```js
for (const target of document.getElementsByClassName('target')) {
  target.textContent = "   Some  text with   various spaces  ";
}
```

```css
.preserve-whitespace {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.target {
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target preserve-whitespace"></div>
```